# SharePoint 2013 Globally Reusable Workflow - Only One Approval List Wanted In Root Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I created a global reusable workflow in SharePoint 2013 using SPD. I associated the workflow with a specific content type. This workflow is now available in all sub-sites in lists that I bound the this specific content type. This all works pretty well.

However, the IT department wants to only use the one approval task list in the root site. Every time a user updates the list in a sub site, the workflow starts running in that sub site and routes to an approval task list in the sub site. I want all the workflows for my content type in all the sub sites to use the approval task list in the root site.

Is this possible? If not, any work around suggestions?

Thanks in advance.
Riaan

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear this was ever answered, but no, every workflow running has to have a task list in the same site. You'd have to develop a task list rollup to get that type of functionality.